# Different height of CSS grid cells

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How can I move up the "content" and the "right" block responsive? The problem is I can't use sub nested grid. I don't need hacks: no margin-top because header can be a different height. No javascript. Only pure CSS. If at all possible.

[image]

Now my markup looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
          "aside header header"
          "left content right";
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.header, .aside, .left, .content, .right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 30px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  height: 80px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: yellow;
}

.left, .content, .right {
  height: 100px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <!-- this order should be on mobile -->
   <header class="header">header</header>
   <aside class="aside">aside</aside>
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="content">content</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can u create 2 separate grids? one for upper row and other for the lower row

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A solution (using CSS only) is by adding another row to your `grid-template-areas:`

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
          "aside header header"
          "aside content right"
          "left content right";
  grid-gap: 15px;

}

.header, .aside, .left, .content, .right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height:30px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  height: 80px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: yellow;

}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: yellow;
}

.left, .content, .right {
  height: 100px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <!-- this order should be on mobile -->
   <header class="header">header</header>
   <aside class="aside">aside</aside>
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="content">content</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this sort of thing (margin-top) to move the content and right closer to the header. If this alters the view on mobile and makes it messy you will need to create 2 views depending on device and use different css values for different devices.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
          "aside header header"
          "left content right";
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.header, .aside, .left, .content, .right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  height: 30px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  height: 80px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.left, .content, .right {
  height: 100px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <!-- this order should be on mobile -->
   <header class="header">header</header>
   <aside class="aside">aside</aside>
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="content">content</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. But what about a different height of the "header" block? It's responsive too.

Comment: You say the header could be responsive, does that mean that it could be as big as the user makes it or is it max a certain height ?

Comment: For me this is not a good solution because if header content change and is more than 50px, the header and the content will collapse.

Answer (score -2):

Check this

```css
    .wrapper {
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:
              "aside header header"
              "left content right";
      grid-gap: 15px;
    }

    .header, .aside, .left, .content, .right {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .header {
      grid-area: header;
      height: 30px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
    }

    .aside {
      grid-area: aside;
      height: 80px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
    }

    .left {
      grid-area: left;
    }

    .content {
      grid-area: content;
      background: yellow;
      float: left;
    }

    .right {
      grid-area: right;
      background: yellow;
      float: right;
    }

    .left, .content, .right {
      height: 100px; /* in real case it's responsive height */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
       <!-- this order should be on mobile -->
       <div id="left-side">
         <aside class="aside">aside</aside>
         <div class="left">left</div>
       </div>

       <div id="right-side">
         <header class="header">header</header>

         <div id="right-side2">
           <div class="content">content</div>
           <div class="right">right</div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: He said that the order needs to stay the same, this is a good solution if you could move the DIV's around.

Comment: Downvote for lack of explanation